# Function call argument is an uninitialized value?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, sqlite

I have been trying to figure out why the Analyzer in Xcode seems to like the this code, so maybe someone can see what is wrong. Gives me this message: "Function call argument is an uninitialized value".

It has a problem with this line and complains about the "statement":

```
if (sqlite3_exec(MysDB, delete_stmt, NULL, statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
```

Actual Code:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if (buttonIndex == 1) {
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &MyDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *deleteSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM DATATABLE WHERE ID = %d", recordID];

        const char *delete_stmt = [deleteSQL UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_exec(MysDB, delete_stmt, NULL, statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

            NSLog(@"Deleted");            
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Not Deleted");
        }
        sqlite3_close(MyDB);
    }
}

More Code Here Removed on Purpose...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd parameter of sqlite3_exec is the callback function, which is currently NULL in your example. And the 4th parameter is the argument to this callback.

http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html

So, I think it doesn't like the fact that you're giving an actual argument to a NULL callback function.

Comment: Thank you - This fixed it. I cannot believe that I did not see this. I looked at it for hours.

Answer (score 3):

You don't initialize `sqlite3_stmt *statement;` (right under `if (buttonIndex == 1) {`) to any particular value when you make it. And you use it in that `sqlite3_exec3()` function.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The problem was fixed with Ushox's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a typo on that line.  The first argument to `sqlite3_exec`, `MysDB` should probably be `MyDB`.

Comment: I took out the actual name of the database - it was not important here. Thank you for answering and helping.